# UWP Change theme in pop ups MVVM Light

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm-light

```
public static async Task SetRequestedThemeAsync()
        {
            foreach (var view in CoreApplication.Views)
            {
                await view.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
                    {
                        frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = Theme;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

This is my code that correctly changes the theme of views in my app, but now I have some ContentDialogs and they don't change their theme.
So in this case I wanna ask two questions:

1. I content my popups in static full properties. Is this a good decision or will be better to create a new obj of popup every time?
2. If static properties are a good decision, how to change themes in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ContentDialogs and they don't change their theme.

It's looks known issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2331). please feel free vote up this report. and currently there is a workaround that set the dialog's theme when show popup like the following.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
    dialog.Title = "Save your work?";
    dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Save";
    dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Don't Save";
    dialog.CloseButtonText = "Cancel";
    dialog.DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary;
    dialog.Content = "Test Theme";
    dialog.RequestedTheme = (Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement).RequestedTheme;


    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

}
```

Comment: But my Settings are ContentDialog too. And I need to dynamically change his theme and background. I also have problems with this.

Comment: The other way is custom ContentDialog's style, and set it with different theme resource.